# 'for given V' or 'for a given V'

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

It is in a scientific paper. I have a parameter V.

Is it 'for given V' or 'for a given V'?

I mean a given value of V, say, V=3. The full sentence is,

for given V, the function f(x;V) is always a convex function of x.

Comment: Please provide more context. What does V represent? Quote the full sentence with "given V".

Comment: a: non-specific value, the: specific value Ex. For a given value V, X is always less than V*2. For the given value V=4, X is less than 8.

Answer (score 3):

The usual phrase is

> a given value

or

> given values

which denotes the initial condition(s) of a calculation

> for a given value of *x*
>   for given values of *x*

I think you might be trying to say

> for given values of V, the function f(x;V) is always convex